# 777 permission for root owned folder

Tags: permissions, x11

The following folder has 777 permission however, it is owned by the root.

```
[root@cluster tmp]# ls -la
drwxrwxrwt   2 root          root           4096 Oct 16 21:53 .X11-unix/
```

So, a user can not delete his file (vnc lock) in that folder. How can I grant that for all user. Then they will be able to remove their vnc lock without root permission.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue you have here is the sticky bit (t) Since you are looking at a directory in this case, the sticky bit stops anyone but the owner of the directory from removing or renaming files within the directory.

To allow user to do what you require, you would need to remove the sticky bit from the folder attributes.

Comment: Yes, this is the answer. `drwxrwxrwt` in the output of `ls -l` indicates a directory with permissions of 1777, rather than 777.

Comment: So, what is the command to drop the sticky bit?

Comment: As root, you will need to chmod -t <directoryname>

Comment: The sticky bit on a directory requires you to own a file to unlink it. Once you remove it any user will be able to delete any file in the directory, which may not be exactly what you were aiming for.